# Why does updating `rgdal` package in R change output of `sp::CRS` (+towgs84=0,0,0)?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sp

I am not a GIS expert, and this change caused quite some errors in our analysis. So my question is, why this was changed: From rgdal 1.4.8 to 1.5.16, the `+towgs84=0,0,0` disappeard in the output of `sp::CRS`.

I hope for an answer, which is comprehensive to a non-GIS-expert.

Reproducible example if you have NO sp and NO rgdal package installed:

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sp/sp_1.4-1.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
 
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/rgdal_1.4-8.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")

packageVersion("sp")
# [1] ‘1.4.1’
packageVersion("rgdal")
# [1] ‘1.4.8’

sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
# CRS arguments:
#   +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0
```

So everything works, that is in our case

```
spdf <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  coords = mission_coords[, c(2,1)],
  data = mission_coords,
  proj4string = sp::CRS(
    "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
df_in <- sp::over(spdf , departement_boundaries , fn = NULL)
```

are ok. (I have problem to make a small reproducible example - the `departement_boundaries` from Zurich are open source, but its a huge string from dput.)

Now, update both packages

```
install.packages("rgdal")
# also installing the dependency ‘sp’
packageVersion("sp")
# [1] ‘1.4.2’
packageVersion("rgdal")
# [1] ‘1.5.16’
```

and in any case +towgs84=0,0,0  is missing now:

```
sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs",
        doCheckCRSArgs = TRUE)
# CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs",
        doCheckCRSArgs = FALSE) # ... +ellps=WGS84 is added...(?)
# CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Any ideas for an explanation to a GIS-newbie?

---

@EdzerPebesma’s answer helped me find [R spatial follows GDAL and PROJ development](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html) to get information:

```
x <- sp::CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
cat(comment(x), "\n")
```

---

One comment from that site is really unclear to me (perhaps how this relates to `+towgs84=`?):

- rgdal generates many warnings about discarded PROJ string keys,
  -> See e.g. Warnung in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO")
  Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition, but +towgs84= values preserved
  from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/371466/121504)?
- intended to alert package maintainers and script authors to the need to review code.
  -> To me it is not clear, what I have to do, see the link above.
- It is particularly egregious to assign to the CRS object projargs slot directly,
  and this is unfortunately seem in much code in packages.
  -> Again, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underlying library, PROJ, has changed dramatically over the past few years, and this is a consequence. The time has come to stop using proj.4 strings. See also this blog post https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html which announced upcoming changes to r-spatial.

Comment: This is quite exciting and I have been rewriting code to accommodate this change to WKT. But, how mature is this new deployment of PROJ/GDAL across other spatial packages (ie., sp, raster)? Can we just start retooling our packages to incorporate WKT projections with any spatial object and projection operation outside of sf >0.9? Are there helper functions such as `sp::is.projected` and ways to compare projections for validation that will work with the new format?

Comment: Perhaps, you also know the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/371466/121504)? To me it is really unclear, what I have to do, in order to improve my packages. See my edit after I read your link. (I am struggling with the implications of "stop using proj.4 strings".)

Comment: To Jeffrey: `sp` and `rgdal` follow this (actually `rgdal` has pioneered this); the `raster` author has been informed, but I believe `raster` still uses on proj4 strings to define CRSs. Not sure what `terra` does. Please follow r-sig-geo for news on sf, sp and rgdal.