# What do the warnings generated from `raster::crs` in `sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame` mean? [R]

Tags: coordinate-system, r

Take the latest versions as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/371463/121504):

```
install.packages("rgdal")
# also installing the dependency ‘sp’
packageVersion("sp")
# [1] ‘1.4.2’
packageVersion("rgdal")
# [1] ‘1.5.16’
```

In this case, the `over` function returns many warnings which we don't understand:

```
# Warnung in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO")
# Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition,
# but +towgs84= values preserved
```

---

Details:

```
class(spdf)
# [1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"
class(departement_boundaries)
# [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"
raster::crs(spdf)
# CRS arguments:
#  +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
raster::crs(departement_boundaries)
# CRS arguments:
# +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0
```

So everything seems ok to me, but:

```
df_in <- sp::over(spdf , departement_boundaries , fn = NULL)
# Warnung in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO")
# Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition,
# but +towgs84= values preserved
# Warnung in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO")
# Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition,
# but +towgs84= values preserved
# Warnung in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO")
# Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition,
# but +towgs84= values preserved
# Warnung in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO")
# Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition,
# but +towgs84= values preserved
```

Comments:

- I have problems to make a small reproducible example - the departement_boundaries from Zurich are open source, but its a huge string from dput.
- The docs `?sp::over` discuss the data.frame cases `x = "SpatialPointsDataFrame", y = "SpatialPolygons"` and `x = "SpatialPoints", y = "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"` but this code ran with previous versions of sp and rgdal (see link above in this question) without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get errors, you get warnings. When you load `rgdal`, it prints a message

```
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.
```

when you want to get rid of the warnings, follow that advice, and try setting

```
options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none")
```

(in absence of a reproducible example this is a guess, really - let me know if it worked!)

Comment: BEFORE loading rgdal library is crucial ;-)

Comment: Could you have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/372692/121504)? There is a lot of useful information in the comments, but for me it is really unclear what this means, to somebody who is "just using" packages without deep knowledge of the GIS-foundations (yet). Thanks a lot!