# Proper way to assign CRS in rgdal 1.5-23

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, rgdal

Perhaps my question has been already answered but if it did, I haven´t be able to find it. I´ve updated the rgal package to version 1.5-23 (GDAL 3.2.1 & PROJ 7.2.1) and when I run the following line

```
crs(res_data_PA) <- LAEA
```

I get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid in Proj4 definition
```

I´m aware that I [can get rid of it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371466/what-do-the-warnings-generated-from-rastercrs-in-spspatialpointsdataframe) and since it´s not an error nothing should change in my data. I don´t like to suppress any type of message from R so, I would like to know how is it now the proper way to assign the CRS to my raster.

Comment: What's your LAEA string here?

Comment: @Spacedman, do you mean this?
 LAEA <-"+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: Solved! Thank you

Comment: You added "+datum=WGS84" to the string?

Comment: Yes. And no more warning messages.